# Columna con números y strings

Tags: r, rstudio

He hecho una encuesta con 1000 registros. Tengo una variable en la que el encuestado debía meter un valor númerico, pero alguno ha introducido cosas"Tres". R reconoce la columna como "character", ya que no todos son números claro.

¿Hay alguna manera de detectar valores no númericos o distintos de (1,2,3,4,5...) para poder editarlos? La única solución que veo sería hacerlo manualmente con Excel.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Bienvenido Luis Rouco Ferriz a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda que agregues un ejemplo de los datos y de la salida que buscas

Answer (score 0):

Sí, se puede.

## Detectar los valores no numéricos

Si ya tienes los datos importados como `character` es fácil encontrar las filas/elementos del vector en los que tienes problemas. `as.numeric()` intentará convertir a una cadena que es expresión literal de un número (como lo serían "1", "2") a `numeric`. Cuando no encuentre una cadena de caracteres válida como número  entonces regresará `NA` y luego puedes identificar esos `NA`.

```
#Simulo unos datos con el problema
números <- c(1, 2, "tres")
#Lo paso a numérico, fallará cuando no hay un número
as.numeric(números)
[1]  1  2 NA
Warning message:
NAs introducidos por coerción 

# Identifico los NA

which(is.na(as.numeric(números)))
```

Me regresa los números de índice en el vector en los que tengo problemas.

## Corregir los errores

Podrías editarlo "a mano", por ejemplo: `números[3] <- 3` haría el reemplazo. Esto funciona si tienes pocos problemas, pero sería muy lento y tedioso, sobre todo si son muchas las correcciones. Como esto es R hay una librería que lo hace ;)

La librería `spanish` que está en CRAN tiene una función para convertir números escritos como palabras a números como tales. La función se llama `to_number` y es genial, pero tiene un pequeño problema: no está vectorizada. Es decir, no puede por sí misma aplicarse a todos los elementos de un vector. Por eso tenemos que vectorizarla primero usando `Vectorize`. En el caso más favorable (los números están correctamente escritos como palabras en español) ni siquiera es necesario hacer la verificación previa.

```
library(spanish)
números <- c(1, 2, "tres", "CUATRO", "dos mil quinientos")
to_number_vec <- Vectorize(to_number)  #La vectorizo
to_number_vec(números)

         1                  2               tres             CUATRO dos mil quinientos 
         1                  2                  3                  4               2500
```

Dos advertencias:

1. No funciona para fracciones o decimales, solo enteros (lo que parece ser tu caso)
2. No funciona y da un error poco informativo si la cadena tiene un número mal escrito. Por ejemplo, falla con "docientos".

Mucha suerte, limpiar datos de campos libres es **o**rrible